# How to embed an arbitrary graph into (k,d)-kautz space (like multidimensional scaling of non-normed space)

Tags: optimization, combinatorial-optimization, graphs, machine-learning

How to embed an arbitrary graph into (k,d)-kautz space (like multidimensional scaling of non-normed space)? See details in the following.

Given a graph $G = \{V,E\}$,
we have a distance matrix (the shortest path matrix of $G$)

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{D}_t=\{\theta_{u,v}|\forall v,u\in V\},
\end{equation}
how to embed the graph $G$ into the $(k,d)$-kautz metric space, that is, optimize the coordinate $x_v$ of each node $v$ in the $(k,d)$-kautz metric space to minimize the difference between $\rho(x_v,x_u)$ and the distance matrix $\mathbf{D}_t$, as
\begin{equation} \label{eq:kautz_mds}
    \min_{\{x_v|\forall v \in V\}} \sum_{\forall v,u\in V} |\rho(x_v,x_u) - \theta_{u,v}| \ \  (1)
\end{equation}
where the coordinate $x_v$ is a string of $k$ characters and $\rho(x_v,x_u)$ represents the distance between $x_v$ and $x_u$.
In the coordinate string $x_v$, each character has $d$ choices, and the adjacent characters are different, which is formulated as
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
        &x_v = a_{1,v} a_{2,v} ...a_{2,v}...a_{k,v},\\
        % \textrm{s.t.\ }
        &\textrm{where}\ \ \forall i\in[1,k-1], a_{i,v} \in [1,d], \ a_{i,v}\neq a_{i+1,v}.
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}
The distance $\rho(x_v,x_u)$ is  the length of the longest common prefix and suffix between $x_v$ and $x_u$, which is formulated as
\begin{equation}
    \rho(x_v,x_u)= k-\max(lcp(x_v,x_u), lcp(x_u,x_v))
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    lcp(x_v,x_u) = \max\ i,\ \ \textrm{s.t.}\ a_{1,v}... a_{i,v} = a_{k-i+1,u}... a_{k,u}
\end{equation}
The optimization problem in Eq. (1) is equivalent to
\begin{equation} \label{eq:kautz_mds_transform}
    \min_{\hat V_s} \|\mathbf{D}_t-S(\mathbf{D}_s,\hat V_s)\|,\ \textrm{s.t.}\ \hat V_s \subset V_s, |\hat V_s| = |V| \ll |V_s|, (2)
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf{D}_s$ is the distance matrix of all feasible coordinates in the $(k,d)$-kautz metric space,
\begin{equation} 
\mathbf{D}_s=\{\rho(x_v,x_u)|\forall v,u\in V_s\},\
\end{equation}
$V_s$ is the set of all feasible coordinates in the $(k,d)$-kautz metric space, and
$S$ is to select a sub-matrix $S(\mathbf{D}_s,\hat V_s)$ from $\mathbf{D}_s$, \ie the distance matrix of $\hat V_s$.
The problem in Eq. (2) is to select some coordinates $\hat V_s\subset V_s$ as the coordinates of
all nodes in the graph $G$ to minimize the difference between the target distance matrix $\mathbf{D}_t$ and the distance matrix $S(\mathbf{D}_s,\hat V_s)$ of $\hat V_s$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/444941/how-to-embed-an-arbitrary-graph-into-k-d-kautz-space-like-multidimensional-sc